# User profile / User roles question

Tags: users

I have setup a website for three choirs in different age groups:

- Adults (18y and up)
- Adolescents (12-18y)
- Children (8-12y)

Some members are related (parent-child-sibling), others are not.

I've created three user roles, one for each choir. And by using User Role Fields, and Field Permission modules I've managed to add fields to the user profile, depending on the roles the user belongs to, to put member related data for that specific user role (birthday, voice, etc...). But there are two problems with this approach:

1. What if a parent has two children beloning to the same age group? For now, I can only add 1 childs details.
2. If a child has his/her own account, can I share the user role fields, and make them visible/editable by both child and parent?
   And while I'm at it:

   - Can I make some fields editable by both parent and child, and some only by the parent? e.g: the field "has to be picked up after rehearsal" would be only editable by parents, not by children themselves...

I know it's complicated, I've allready spent a lot of time searching modules. But maybe my experience with Drupal is just too limited to see the possibilities/strengths/weaknesses of these modules, since it's my first Drupal site...

Writing this up, I came up with a different approach: can I create a profile for each user : parent/children. And then setup some relationship to make the childs profile editable by the parent? But, what about the fields that would be only editable by the parent?